Trigger on 4 distinct git repositories(Yocto and 3 repositories with dependencies) gives broken git configuration for main repo
I have a project where I build Yocto which includes software from 3 other repositories.
I trigger on 3 of the repositories and the main Yocto repository.
When the job triggers on the dependencies, the Sanity step that I added (see YAML) fails because the git submodule configuration is completely broken.
repo1.git is my Yocto repository. The other repositories are dependencies.
I'm using the following YAML file:
trigger:
 branches:
   include:
   - main
 paths:
   include:
   - repo/path1
   exclude:
   - repo

resources:
  repositories:

  - repository: repo1.git
    type: git

  - repository: repo2.git
    type: git

  - repository: repo3.git
    type: git

  - repository: repo4.git
    type: git

jobs:
- job: buildjob
  timeoutInMinutes: 360 # 6 hours
  pool:
    name: Default
    demands:
      - agent.name -equals agent1

  steps:

  - checkout: self
#    submodules: true
#    persistCredentials : true
#    clean: false

  - checkout: repo1.git
    submodules: true
    persistCredentials : true
    clean: false

  - bash: |
      cd repo1 || exit 1

      git reset --hard
      git submodule foreach --recursive git reset --hard
      git submodule update --init --recursive
    displayName: 'Clean up in git and submodules'

  - bash: |
      cd repo1 || exit 1

      if [ "$(Build.Repository.Name)" != "repo1.git" ]; then
        echo "Not a repo1 change, using latest from repo1"
        git fetch origin || exit 1
        git checkout origin/scarthgap || exit 1
        git log -n1
      fi
      git submodule update --init --recursive || exit 1
      git submodule status --recursive || exit 1
    displayName: 'Configure submodules'

  - bash: |
      cd repo1 || exit 1
      OUTPUT_FILE="${PWD}/output.log"
      source init-build-env &> ${OUTPUT_FILE} || exit 1

      if grep -q 'ERROR:' "${OUTPUT_FILE}"; then
        echo "Found errors"
        cat ${OUTPUT_FILE}
        exit 1
      else
        echo "No errors"
      fi
      
    displayName: 'Sanity (errors from init-build-env)'

  - bash: |
      cd repo1 || exit 1

      source init-build-env || exit 1


What is wrong here? Is this not supported?
The step named "Configure submodules" prints correct git log, but the next step doesn't work as if the git repository points to something old (wrong Yocto branch).
To me it looks like the following:
if [ "$(Build.Repository.Name)" != "repo1.git" ]; then
        echo "Not a repo1 change, using latest from repo1"
        git fetch origin || exit 1
        git checkout origin/scarthgap || exit 1
        git log -n1
fi
      git submodule update --init --recursive || exit 1
      git submodule status --recursive || exit 1

leaves the repository in a weird state.
source init-build-env

is from Yocto and checks that submodules match.
It gives the following output:
Found errors
NOTE: Starting bitbake server...
ERROR: Layer meta-repo1 is not compatible with the core layer which only supports these series: nanbield (layer is compatible with scarthgap)
ERROR: Layer meta-repo1 is not compatible with the core layer which only supports these series: nanbield (layer is compatible with scarthgap)

This happens only if the repository triggered is different from repo1.git which contains Yocto.

Can you show the error log? and have you tried to identify which command in sanity task caused the failure?

I updated the question. Thanks for looking at this @wadezhou-MSFT. :)

After reading https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops (again) I realized that I didn't specify "ref" for the repository in which the CI files are stored. The first trigger is for this repository. Perhaps this is the problem.

"When a pipeline is triggered, Azure Pipelines has to determine the version of the YAML file that should be used and a version for each repository that should be checked out. .. If a change to any other repository resource triggers the pipeline, then the latest version of YAML from the default branch of self repository is used." - so the default branch is the one set from "ref" option for each repository. The only repository that I didn't set this for was "self".

Do you mean you are not checking out correct ref, and fixed by add 'ref' to checkout correct branch?

The repository that I'm building is not being checked out using the correct ref when one of the dependencies trigger the build. I made a workaround where other pipelines trigger a build of Yocto after they finish building instead of using repositories with dependencies as described in this question. :)

Thanks @wojciii for your sharing. Glad to know it's resolved. It's recommended to put the detail in the reply to answer yourself, so that more members can benefit from it.
